# Draw at the end of turn in Carcassonne

Tags: house-rules, carcassonne

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pre-drawing cards or tiles](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/pre-drawing-cards-or-tiles)

I often play Carcassonne in a lunchtime setting where we are looking to condense playtime as much as possible.  We recently have started allowing players to draw their next tile at the end of their turn giving them more time to plan their next move.  The rule has been working pretty well so far but people are nervous that one of us is going to start exploiting it.  Does anyone see any problems with this rule change?